# Eclipse Indigo JSP validator not fully supporting JSP based tags in a jar file

Tags: eclipse, jsp, validation, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-wtp

If I package my JSP based tag in a jar file Indigo seems to correctly pick up and validate the URI and tag name.

However it doesn't seem to properly recognize any attributes on the tag.  The parser gives me a warning and indicates "undefined attribute name".

However if I take the exact same tag and place it inside the same project (in a differently named tag dir) it is properly parsed by the validator -- indicating that the attribute is required.

In both cases the tags deploy and run properly in the container.

Obviously, this works, but the validator support is a nice feature of WTP that I'd hate to lose for a reusable taglib.

I don't think you can add any extra metadata into the TLD file for a JSP based tag.

Any suggestions?

I suppose as a last resort I could write these in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's possibly http://bugs.eclipse.org/353629 .  Does SR1 help?